# Ubuntu 18.04.4 Server: Blocked port

Tags: server, router

So, I have a [CSGO](https://store.steampowered.com/app/730/CounterStrike_Global_Offensive/) server running on my local server running Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS (Not VM, running as primary boot), connected directly with my router via cable. For this, I had to open port 27015 tcp/udp on my router.

When I test my ports in https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ , it's says that is closed.

**What is weird is that when I try to run anything that listens 27015, and check again, the port opens.**

Things that I've tried:

- Allow the port in ufw
- Disable ufw
- Allow the port on iptables
- Checked my router firewall
- Install Debian instead of Ubuntu (actually i tried first on debian an
  then moved to ubuntu)

**So, how do I know and ensure you guys that I've opened correctly the port on my router?**

Because I installed ssh, and this port 22 was opened in the same way as 27015.
Aaaand before installing Linux, this server was running Windows, and the port was open.

I've installed ssh and with this, Ubuntu automatically open 22 port on my router, and it is working and open.

Conclusions that I've made so far:

- The router it is OK, nothing to do with that
- Both Ubuntu and Debian have the same blocking
- **The port only opens when a process it's listening that port (CSGO for some reason do not open the port when running)**

Comment: Well, the clue must be in your last sentence. If CSGO was listening on that port, it wouldn't have been reported as closed; moreover, you wouldn't have been able to start another process listening at that port (it would get an "port is already in use" error). So do `sudo netstat -tulnp` and see if CSGO is listening on another port, or not listening at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jos! I will try that tonight! I think maybe that is the problem, CSGO isn't listening anything. But on Windows you don't need to listen any port to check if it's open. You just go to your router, disable your Win firewall (just for testing), and then bum, it's open. I think is something to do with ports logic in Linux. Thanks!

Comment: @RafaelWille Thats ***not*** how it works on Windows either. If nothing is listening, Windows will refuse connection.

Comment: @K7AAY Added vital information. Sorry about that.

Comment: @vidarlo What i mean is that, even if Windows refuse the connection, the port will appear as open.

Comment: No, it will not. How would that happen? You can distinguish three states: Connection accepted, connection refused, and connection silently discarded.

Comment: @vidarlo so then, how I opened the port and with no service listening on Windows (not even my server running), returned "open port"? I'm not trying to say that you're wrong, you clearly understand the subject, but in my tests, that's what happened.